# How to get the wells in a bootstrap row giving space between it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and trying to get two `wells` in a row not to be squashed right up against each other but am having trouble. 
This is my code:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 well"> first column</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 well"> second column</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm following a tutorial which has the code written as I have done, but their webpage loads with spaces between the wells.
Can anyone suggest how to get them to have a space between them on the row?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells)

> Use the well as a simple effect on an **element** to give it an inset
>   effect.

So don't use them with `col-*-*` instead  to achieve what you want you can use them as child of `col-*-*`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="well">first column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="well">second column</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## INFO:

Default `well`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well">first column</div>
    <div class="well">second column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Plus you have the optional classes:

> Control padding and rounded corners with two optional modifier
>   classes.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well well-sm">first column</div>
    <div class="well well-lg">second column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The wells are not underneath each other, they are next to each other on the same line but they are touching. I would like to know how to move them apart so that there is space between them. I have tried padding but that only seems to increase the space between the top and bottom of the wells and the edge of the container.